# Creating rectangles from global point data of approximately consistent size in EPSG:3857 using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector-grid

I have a point layer of global city locations taken from the Esri data here:
https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6996f03a1b364dbab4008d99380370ed

I'm trying to create a rectangular bounding box centred on each point for use with maps that are in EPSG:3857 CRS.

I can create the rectangles easily enough by reprojecting the point layer to EPSG:3857 CRS and using "Rectangles, ovals, diamonds" from the processing toolbox. However, the obvious issue is that the size (area) of the rectangles will be distorted as you move away from the equator.

Is there any easy solution to scale these rectangles to an *approximately* consistent size (e.g. by using an expression to modify Width and Height in the processing toolbox)?

For my purposes, a result within 10% or so of the size at the equator for all results would be sufficient.

Comment: Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this workflow:

1. Reproject the point data into an appropriate CRS that *doesn't* use lat/long as its measurement
2. Create rectangles from those points
3. Reproject the rectangles into EPSG:3857

Comment: I thought EPSG:3857 didn't use lat/long? If I use a different CRS and reproject the rectangles to EPSG:3857, won't the rectangles end up warped?

Comment: Hmmm, I may be about to learn something here!  Perhaps your problem is the way Mercator exaggerates areas toward the poles.  So what happens when you reproject to Robinson or Winkel Tripel, create the rectangles, then reproject back to 3857?

Comment: This helped get me on the right track. Creating the rectangles in WGS 84/Plate Carree gives me consistent height globally for the rectangles. When reprojected to EPSG:3857 the shape is distorted ("fatter" rectangles near the equator and "skinner" near the poles) but I can use the height of these rectangle to draw new rectangles in EPSG:3857 that should serve my purpose.